# Dell 3110cn Printer doesn't have new mac drivers?

Tags: macos, drivers, printer

The company I work for recently purchased several new MacBooks for use around the office, but our Dell 3110cn printer doesn't seem to be compatible with them. It uses only a generic UNIX driver, so printing is extremely limited, and we can't change the printer settings for glossy, or heavy paper, leading to problems with posters.

To make matters worse, the only Mac OS X driver Dell had on their support page for said printer was for PowerPC based Macs. Because of this, they were incompatible. Can anyone possibly point me in the direction of a viable driver for our Macs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mac OSX comes with an extensive range of PS drivers. Unfortunately, Dell does not appear to be among them. And, as you've found out, the only drivers available from Dell are too old.

The 3110cn is a PostScript printer, so the driver is part of OSX, but it needs to be told about printer specifics. This is done with the printer's PPD file. As it's a text file, the Windows version will work fine on the Mac. Search for *.ppd under C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SPOOL. PPDs usually have obvious names, but some manufacturers use cryptic ones. In that case, if you open it in an editor you'll see the printer name near the top of the PPD.

Just install the PPD file on the Mac (in Libraries/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/en.lproj ) and browse to that when installing. [This link](http://www.westwind.com/reference/os-x/where-files.html) gives more details on file locations.

Answer (score 0):

If the drivers are out there at all, you'll probably be able to find them here:
[www.driverguide.com](http://driverguide.com)

Answer (score 0):

Install the driver for the Dell H625cdw.  Then install the 3130CN but manually select the driver for the H625cdw.  Works like a charm on Big Sur for me.

Answer (score -1):

For others who may be looking (particularly since the release of OS X Mavericks), the Mac OS X drivers for the Dell 3130cn seem to work fine on the Dell 3110cn. I've been using them for several months now without a problem.